# RxSwift: How to merge array of Completable to Completable

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have some array of values in my code and I'd like to pass it through sequence of Single and Completable methods:

```
let data: [DataClass]

func method1(_ data: DataClass) -> Single<DataClass2> { ... }
func method2(_ data2: DataClass2) -> DataClass3? { ... }
func method3(_ data3: DataClass3) -> Completable { ... }
```

I try to do it with this code:

```
func iNeededMethod() -> Completable {

    return Completable.merge(
      data
        .flatMap { value -> Completable in
          method1(value)
            .map(method2)
            .filter { $0 != nil }
            .map { $0! }
            .map(method3)
    })
  }
```

But it doesn't work for me with error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'PrimitiveSequence<MaybeTrait, Completable>' (aka 'PrimitiveSequence<MaybeTrait, PrimitiveSequence<CompletableTrait, Never>>') to closure result type 'Completable' (aka 'PrimitiveSequence<CompletableTrait, Never>')
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your expression looks to complex to understand. It would be easier for yourself and others to understand if you break it down into variables. What is your data, array of DataClass, what is DataClass it it some class of ObservableType or PrimitiveType ?

Comment: `method3` is Completable. I think you can't use that in a .map like that. You need to put it in a flatMap or maybe an .andThen ?